# Which method/ class is throwing this error message?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

When I try to reach the backend of the extension I made for TYPO3 v9.5.9, I get this error message:

[image: The Error Message]

To fix it, I want to find out which class/ method is throwing this error message. Does anyone know how I can find that out?

my composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "secsign/secsign",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "This extension allows users to authenticate using their smart phone running the SecSign App.",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "SecSign Technologies Inc.",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^9.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "Classes"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Secsign\\Secsign\\Tests\\": "Tests"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "secsign/secsign": "self.version",
        "typo3-ter/secsign": "self.version"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is TYPO3 installed in composer mode? If yes: What does its composer.json file look like? Does it have your extension referenced?

Comment: Yes it is. How would I have to reference the extension there? I have this in there. ```  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
   "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "Classes"
        }
    }  ```  I do not have anything about my  extension in the require segment.

Comment: Note that your "replace" section actually holds a contradiction: You tell composer to replace the version you are just installing with itself. Remove this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you added something like this in your composer.json (when the file is from a custom ext, not 3rd party)

```
{
    // ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/SECSIGNEXT/Classes/",
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In the extension's composer.json or the project's composer.json?

Comment: the projects composer.json. but you dont need this, when this is a 3rd party extension installed by composer.

Comment: If "secsign" is your own extension, do NOT fiddle with your project's composer.json file, but get your extension right.

Comment: sure you can have your own extensions in a better shape. my solution is a fast helper for the asked problem. read more about the mentioned workaround here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/MigrateToComposer/MigrationSteps.html#include-individual-extensions-like-site-packages

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your autoload configuration in `composer.json` of your extension is correct. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4
2. Run "composer dumpautoload" / Or use the button in the Install Tool if this is a non-composer installation
3. Flush all caches

Comment: I have added the composer.json file to the question. I have tried dumping and flushing and also deleting and reinstalling the extension but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: make sure the autoload path ends with a trailing slash.
```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Secsign\\Secsign\\": "Classes/"
        }
    },
```